# background image proportions for responsive design

Tags: responsive-design

I am using a background image that is 3870px by 3997px. I have used the following css to make it cover the whole screen:

```
body {
url('../images/bkg_large.png') no-repeat center center fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
}
```

However, the image does not seem to fit properly. It is stretched out and cuts out the clouds in the top part of the image. I tried removing fixed and adding height=100% instead. This makes the clouds appear for a regular lap top screen but still does not fix it on larger monitors.

This is the website: http://heartcrossings.businesscatalyst.com/

Is there something else I can do to make this image work better on larger monitors?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will fix it but worth a shot

Try background-size:100%;